# Error installing Gosu on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby

Getting the following error when attempting to install the Gosu gem on Ubuntu. I have already installed the dependencies.

Here is the error message:

```
compilation terminated.
Makefile:235: recipe for target 'TrueTypeFontUnix.o' failed
make: *** [TrueTypeFontUnix.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/nicolesano/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gosu-0.14.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/nicolesano/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/gosu-0.14.5/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, one package was missing from the dependencies wiki. Just run `sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev` and then try `gem install gosu` again.

Reference: https://github.com/gosu/gosu/issues/514